# Asp.Net Core: How to manage authentication requirement manually (without using [Authorize])

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, authorization

By using standard asp.net core authentication builtin features (not authorization) how to manually decide whether the user needs to be authenticated or not.

For example having some dynamic controller/action:

```cs
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "query_api/{operation}/{query}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "Index" }
    );
    ...

    //[Authorize]
    public class QueryController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly QueryService _queryService;

        public QueryController(QueryService queryService)
        {
            _queryService = queryService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        //[Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string operation, string query)
        {
            return await _queryService.Execute(this, operation, query);
        }
```

I would like to manually decide whether authentication is required or not based on the `operation`. Eg. if the `operation.Equals("public")` the authentication needs to be skipped.

I know about the `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` but it is too late, it's not about authorization, but about authentication. The question is how to control manually whether the authentication is required or not? At the same time I don't want to invent the whole authentication process from scratch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just like what you said, what you need is authentication but not authorization, but in controller, we can only do authorization. In your scenario, I'm afraid you have to prepare 2 kinds of apis, one for public and another for private.....

Comment: @TinyWang sounds like workaround. Thanks for your voice.